# How do you handle maven builds with cross platform code and platform specific testing?

Tags: maven, cross-platform

I have cross platform maven java build.  I want to run the unit tests on each  platforms but only need to compile/package/deploy from one platform.

**For example:**

1. checkout on   windows
2. build-test-package-deploy
3. run unit-tests on other platforms using maven-repo

At present, I'm building and testing on all platform but this consumes resources and results in multiple generation of artifacts which seems wrong from a maven stand point.

How do you handle this situation?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a cross platform build which needs to build on windows, 32bit ubuntu, 64bit ubuntu, and red hat. I develop on 32bit ubuntu and have profiles for all my target environments in the pom files. When I need to test builds I do it in a VM or yell at someone to check out a clean copy and try to build (preferred to make sure there isn't any machine-specific (env variables, local files, etc) stuff messing with it), although most of my code is fairly portable so my situation may not be super relevant for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking more of how the build system handles it.  We have Bamboo and plans setup for each platform.  However, we are generating code multiple times which seems wrong and are running the full suite of tests on each platform (which seems right).  I'd like to build once - but am not sure how this fits in with the standard maven lifecycle